# MediaWiki Category Tree expand all by default

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

Im using the [Category Tree extension](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryTree) for MediaWiki which allows you to create a nice tree view of all categories.

By default when you visit a page with a category tree you have to expand a category manually by clicking the toggle symbol.

Is there a way to expand all categories by default? Where do i have to make changes in code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mediawiki has **Jquery** by default so you can just click with Jquery:

```
$('.CategoryTreeToggle').click();
```

Comment: Thanks man its working! I had to add a code like urs to the MediaWiki:Common.js page. My exact code is: $( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.CategoryTreeToggle[data-ct-state="collapsed"]').click();
});

Comment: Would that be in the "ext.categoryTree.js" file?

Comment: Both code sections didn't worked for me (I got an success only one time after changing MediaWiki:Common.js and after that it tocally stopped). I had this issue with MediaWiki 1.31.3 and an *update to new MediaWiki solved the issue*. It seems versions close to 1.31.3 have some bugs exactly here.